# awk + count the strings from file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have in file /tmp/users list of users ( each list contain diff users )

Example

```
more /tmp/users


root
kafka
yarn
hdfs
root
root
yarn
moon
apache
start
moon
apache
```

I want to print the users that appears in the file **/tmp/users** and count them as the following

Expected results

```
apache - 2
Hdfs - 1
Kafka - 1
Moon - 2
Root - 3
Start - 1
Yarn - 2
```

Comment: see `man sort`, and `man uniq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this with this pipeline, which though may not be the most homogeneous approach:

```
sort /tmp/users | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " - " $1;}'
```

`sort` sorts the input, so that `uniq` can then process the entries. They need to be sorted. Finally `awk` produces the final report, which is a cosmetic operation. (Compare the output without it.)

Also, if the input contains empty lines, you may want to skip them. `perl` comes in handy:

```
perl -lne 'print unless /^\s*$/' in | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " - " $1;}'
```

Here's also a homogeneous Perl one liner:

```
perl -lne '($s)=/(\S+)/; $a{$s}++ if $s; END {print "$_ - $a{$_}" for (sort keys %a)}' /tmp/users
```